# Kotlin inheritnce - No value passed for parameter context

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to build an `AccountAuthenticator` class with kotlin for android. But when trying to implement the `AbstractAccountAuthenticator` class I get the following exception at compile:

`No value passed for parameter context`

I'm not entirely sure what it means and can't find anything on how to solve it.

Here is the relevant code:

```
import android.accounts.AbstractAccountAuthenticator
import android.accounts.Account
import android.accounts.AccountAuthenticatorResponse
import android.os.Bundle

class AccountAuthenticator: AbstractAccountAuthenticator() {}
```

Does anyone know what this means, why, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`AbstractAccountAuthenticator`'s [constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html#AbstractAccountAuthenticator(android.content.Context)) takes a `Context context` parameter. So you'll have to pass a `Context` to it somehow, for example, your `AccountAuthenticator` could also have a `Context` parameter:

```
class AccountAuthenticator(context: Context): AbstractAccountAuthenticator(context) {}
```

Comment: That fixed it thank you. Just worth adding in that context is imported from `android.content.Context`. Only detail I was missing.

Comment: Simply speaking, i transfer/ pass the "context" parameter from Inherited class to Base class super method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Kotlin but `AbstractAccountAuthenticator` constructor takes a `Context` see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html#AbstractAccountAuthenticator(android.content.Context)).

So I guess you have to implement this constructor and other related abstract methods.